# Change name of "Figure" and "References" in ACM SIG alternate

Tags: languages, acm, changes

I want to change the words *Figure* and *References* into another language, using [ACM SIG alternate template](https://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/proceedings-templates). Any ideas how I can achieve this?

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

This is a test.

\begin{figure}[hbt]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{test_image}
\caption{Test Figure}
\end{figure}

And here is a reference: \cite{testCite}.

\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{citations}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is the ACM allowing this?

Comment: That's a good question! I don't know to be honest - but I hope so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class hardwires the names; it's easy to change this though.

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
% don't use hardwired names
\def\fnum@figure{\figurename\ \thefigure}
\def\fnum@table{\tablename\ \thetable}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{References}{\refname}{}{}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{References}{\refname}{}{}
% fix a silly usage of \uppercase in \@sect
\patchcmd{\@sect}{\uppercase}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@sect}{\uppercase}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

This is a test.

\begin{figure}[hbt]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.48\columnwidth]{example-image}
\caption{Test Figure}
\end{figure}

And here is a reference: \cite{testCite}.

%\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
%\bibliography{citations}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem{testCite} Something

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

The change has no consequence in case `babel` is not used. I added a mock `thebibliography` environment just to show the effect.

Note that you should use `\columnwidth` and not `\textwidth` for the figure.

[image]

Comment: @Johannes_B Good remark!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! It works all fine now :)
But there is one small thing: is it possible to write the new word for *references* (in my case *Literatur*) also completely in upper case (like all other captions)?

Comment: @Paul85 Done; the class shows a wealth of silly TeX programming, unfortunately. They seem to think that there is only one language in the world and that accents are just a fancy of European people that insist in using their own language..

Comment: Thanks again, you saved my day! Also good point about the `\columnwidth`! I actually did think the same as you regarding your last sentence ;)

Comment: It's me again. Do you also know a solution for the *ABSTRACT* caption? I tried to modify your code to fit with "abstract", but I couldn't achieve it yet.